# Turning real-life object into X3DOM 3D scene

Tags: web-applications, 3d-modelling, x3dom

I just started to playing a bit with 3d scenes in X3DOM and I wonder if there is any 'best practice' or 'recommended way' (especially some easy one) to turn some real-life object into a 3d scene for X3DOM. Lets say some cup or any other non trivial shape.

My goal is to create something like product configurator which will be capable of rotating the model and some color settings. This is covered pretty nicely within the turorials but now I want to have my own object on the place.

I would be also interested in objections against using the X3DOM and recommendations of other technologies.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The quick path is to use 3DS max and Instant Reality's Exporter
This can create VRML, X3D and X3DOM (xhtml) files

http://www.x3dom.org/?p=575

3DS Max is free to students and for academia users. 
For others and professionals its kinda expensive.

You could find free or cheap X3D models - or explore Rhino or Cinema 4D (less expensive - X3D not X3Dom exporters)

Comment: +1. I was aware of this. I just guess if that object generated from some other 3D format can still be easilly used for product configuration. I mean how do I choose colors of its parts for example when it is some non-trivial shape. Any idea on this?